# Can't change CSS ::after shadow color

Tags: css

Hey so my friend runs this web company. He told me he wanted to make some changes to his site. And if I showed him I could handle it, he'd hire me for some stuff.

Most of it I handled fine. But I can't figure out this for the life of me.

If you go to his site (linked below) and hover over the round plus icon under recent work. The shadow switches to blue. I want it to stay orange though.

Any ideas?

p.s. i changed the icon color, shadow color etc... just can't figure out how to change this one thing.

*link removed

Thanks!

relevant code below :

```
.posts-grid.works li .featured-thumbnail .zoom-icon::after {
    background: #E35F33 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}
.posts-grid.works li .featured-thumbnail .zoom-icon {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 6px rgba(227, 95, 51, 0.2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is one of CSS specificity:

Here's the selector you're trying to overwrite:

```
.posts-grid.works li .featured-thumbnail .zoom-icon:hover { ... }
```

Here's your selector:

```
.posts-grid.works li .featured-thumbnail .zoom-icon { ... }
```

If you can't or don't want to remove the first selector, make your selector more specific.

**Ref:**

- [Specificity - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: I feel so silly i missed that. the :hover wasnt showing up in the browser debugger. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the following code:

```
.posts-grid.works li .featured-thumbnail .zoom-icon:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 6px rgba(90,206,205,0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 0 6px rgba(90,206,205,0.4);
    box-shadow:0 0 0 6px rgba(90,206,205,0.4);
}
```

This seems to fix the issue.